# Earth Engine: Mapping over a feature collection of ROIs

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, feature-collection

I have a function that performs an operation over a specific ROI. Now, I want to apply the same function over a collection of ROIs by mapping the function over a feature collection. 
Haven't found any feasible solution anywhere.

Here's what I am trying:

```
var myfunc = function(feature) {
  var geometry = feature.geometry();

  var L7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA")
      .filterDate('2009-10-01','2010-12-01')
      .filterBounds(geometry)

  var Convert_scale = function(img) {
    var I = ee.Image(img)
    var correct_scale = I.select(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B7']).multiply(0.0001)
    return I.addBands(correct_scale,['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B7'],true)
  }

  L7 = L7.map(Convert_scale)

   return L7;
}

var fc = ee.FeatureCollection("users/climateClass/strips_bross_allin");
var L7coll = ee.ImageCollection(fc.map(myfunc))
print(L7coll) //.first())
Map.addLayer((L7coll).mosaic())
```

The resulting image collection has zero bands and adding first image to map gives a `Layer error`

Here's my [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/5f127758de871184227159c2a43f713f).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your reason `L7coll` fails to display on the map is that it's an `ee.FeatureCollection` where each feature is an `ee.ImageCollection`. I'm guessing you wanted an `ee.ImageCollection` with images. `myfunc()` probably should return an `ee.Image` instead of an `ee.ImageCollection`.

```
var myfunc = function(feature) {
  var geometry = feature.geometry();

  var L7 = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_TOA")
      .filterDate('2009-10-01','2010-12-01')
      .filterBounds(geometry)

  var Convert_scale = function(img) {
    var I = ee.Image(img)
    var correct_scale = I.select(['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B7']).multiply(0.0001)
    return I.addBands(correct_scale,['B1','B2','B3','B4','B5','B7'],true)
  }

  L7 = L7.map(Convert_scale)

   return L7.median(); // Turn your collection into an image in one way or another
}

var fc = ee.FeatureCollection("users/climateClass/strips_bross_allin");
var L7coll = ee.ImageCollection(fc.map(myfunc))
print(L7coll) //.first())
Map.addLayer(L7coll.mosaic(), {bands: 'B3,B2,B1', min: 0, max: 0.00003, gamma: 1.5})
Map.centerObject(fc)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/806525d0a4a96ae06599aa624cb2b716